# Obeject recognition kitchen on Ubunto

Tags: ros, household-objects-database

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to install ORK on ubunto, but if I try to compile, I get the folliowing error

CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"household_objects_database" with any of the following names:

```
household_objects_databaseConfig.cmake
household_objects_database-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "household_objects_database" to
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "household_objects_database_DIR" to a directory
containing one of the above files.  If "household_objects_database"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
tabletop/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.

The package household_object_database is not found, but I have exactly used the instructions on

wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/install.html#install

but I am wondering how I can fix this issue

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187368/obeject-recognition-kitchen-on-ubunto/) by [Martin](https://answers.ros.org/users/19809/martin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're probably missing this package? https://github.com/ros-interactive-manipulation/household_objects_database

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0